# CSS Trick: nth-of-type()

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Hi I am looking to something particular and not even sure if it can be done using pure CSS:

```
<div-1> 
  <div-x></div-x>
  <div-x></div-x>
  <div-x></div-x>
  <div-x></div-x>
<div-1>
```

What I am trying to do in scss is

```
if <div-x> render count is even
  then only apply &:last-child{ something; } to div number len(<div-x>)-1
end
```

**EG:**
  if div-x rendered are 4 then apply pseudo-element to 3rd div-x else dont

I tried below but it applies to all odd  element

```
&:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Any hint/help will be appreciated Thanks !

Comment: could you get by with `:nth-of-type(even):last-child:before` instead of having to do `:after` on the preceding element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `:nth-last-of-type`:

```css
.wrapper div:nth-of-type(even) + div:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
}

/* for when there are only two occurrences of this element type */
.wrapper div:nth-last-of-type(2):first-of-type {
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
```

The first selector will style the penultimate `div` only if it is immediately preceded by an even occurrence of `div`. The second selector is to style the first `div` when it is also the penultimate `div` (when there are only two `div`s). I used two declarations merely for the sake of readability.

Check out [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/wuizu6uh) demo.

However, ensure that support of the pseudo-class is sufficient for your requirements. [This](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-of-type/#browser-support) page (2013) states:

> `:nth-last-of-type` was introduced in CSS Selectors Module 3, which means old versions of browsers do not support it. However, modern browser support is impeccable, and the new pseudo-selectors are widely used in production environments. If you require older browser support, either polyfill for IE, or use these selectors in non-critical ways á la progressive enhancement, which is recommended.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type#Browser_compatibility) MDN page states the following browsers have "basic support" as of the given versions:

```
┌────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ Chrome │ Firefox (Gecko) │ Internet Explorer │ Opera │ Safari │
├────────┼─────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────┼────────┤
│   4.0  │   3.5 (1.9.1)   │        9.0        │  9.5  │   3.2  │
└────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

And for mobile browsers:

```
┌─────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Android │ Firefox Mobile (Gecko) │ IE Mobile │ Opera Mobile │ Safari Mobile │
├─────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│   2.1   │       1.0 (1.9.1)      │    9.0    │     10.0     │      3.2      │
└─────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: I think OP was asking for something to target the element *before* the last element if the *last* element is even.

Comment: If the _last_ element is even, then the _second-to-last_ element is odd, and the _third-to-last_ element is even. The code I provided styles the _second-to-last_ element if the _third-to-last_ element is even. Am I missing something? Doesn't my code demo target the element you described?

Comment: hmmm it seems like it *should* work. I checked the demo and it didnt work for me. (in Chrome)

Comment: my monitor is set to dim mode so the fill color on the demo wasn't very prominent. not your fault :) (also im kinda blind)

Comment: Awesome answer. I never imagined that these would be possible with CSS :)